# javaScript not running when packed with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using webpack the first time, I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/exploring-real-time-apps-with-vuejs-es2016-and-webpack/) to setup the dependencies and write some test code, but there is no result as the tutorial suggested. Thanks for every one to help.

There is the related code:

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/main', // tell webpack to start from ./app/main.js
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import AppComponent from './components/app-component/app-component';
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'app-component': AppComponent
    }
});
```

VueJs component:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const AppComponent = Vue.extend({
    template: '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'
});

export default AppComponent;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue Twitter Streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <app-component></app-component>
</div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `template` option with a string, which requires the Vue compiler but when using `import Vue from 'vue'` it only imports the Vue runtime. Instead you have to import the file `dist/vue.esm.js` in the Vue module, which includes the compiler as well. You'd have to change your imports to:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm';
```

Alternatively you can use webpacks [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to define an alias, so when you import `vue` it will import `vue/dist/vue.esm` instead.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
}
```

For more information see [Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

You can also use [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) with a `.vue` file, which will require you to configure [`vue-loader`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader). With that you only need the runtime.